# Shorten Integer-Array JSON Representation

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

In my JS-application I'm uploading documents to a server.
The documents are stored in `Uint8Array`'s. That means documents are represented as `Arrays` consisting of Integers.

Before uploading the documents I `JSON.stringify` the documents. 
Here you have an example:

```
  var document = [0,5,5,7,2,234,1,4,2,4]
  JSON.stringify(document)
  => "[0,5,5,7,2,234,1,4,2,4]"
```

Then I send the JSON-representation to the Server.

**My problem is that the JSON-representation has a much bigger file-size than the original Integer-Array. I guess that's because the `Array` is transformed to a `JSON-String`. I send much more data to the server then needed. How can I store the data more compressed in JSON?**

I thought, the JSON-representation is maybe smaller, if I convert the Array first to Base64 and then to JSON.

What are your ideas? Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you don't actually want JSON.

Comment: Have you tried BSON?

Comment: What are the contents of the array? Would you have any value in the 0-255 range in about equal proportions, or would you have more ASCII-like values? Base64 will give you a better ratio than the above JSON array representation: one byte will result in an average of 1.33 bytes, while the array representation will result in 3.57 bytes. But if you have mostly ASCII-like data, you could go down to close to 1 byte...

Comment: There is this [lz-string compression library](http://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/demo.html) for JS which presumably compresses the string to 25% of it's original size. Might be useful if you have large JSON data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integer array JSON representation results in an average 3.57 ratio between input and output:

- 10 values are represented by 2 bytes (one digit, one comma)
- 90 values by 3 bytes (2 digits, one comma)
- 156 values by 4 bytes

On the other hand, base64 will result in an average 1.333... ratio (3 bytes are encoded as 4).

If you have mostly ASCII-like characters in your array (i.e. in the range 32-126), you would probably be better off just sending them as strings (with a few characters escaped), but not if you have random 8-bit data.

You could use some kind of base94 representation to get a better ratio over base64, but is it really worth the cost?

Also note that if you may also consider compression of the data.